# How to calculate wavelet energy?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelets

Part of my assignment about signal processing says the following:

> - Compute the Discrete Wavelet Transform for the input signals
> - Group the wavelet coefficients in trees growing across scales
> - Classify the trees in high- and low-energy trees

I've managed to implement my own DWT, calculate the coefficients and group them in trees.

Now I'm left with calculating the energy of the wavelet coefficients.

> **Question:** How to calculate the energy of wavelet coefficients?

I am doing this in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

If such coefficients are calculated from an orthonormal basis, rather than from a redundant wavelet transform like the discrete case of a CWT, then **the energy is the sum of the square of the absoute values** of those coefficients, because ortho*normal* wavelet bases converge in norm, and the energy of a signal is defined as the integral of its absolute value.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)